# Excel VBA copy the results in a For loop and paste it into a new sheets with numbers only

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to VBA, and I have tried to write a paragraph to copy the results in a `For` loop and paste it into a new sheets with numbers only.

```
Range(Cells(42, 1), Cells(86, 20)).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("output").Select
b = 1 + 35 * a
Range(Cells(b, 1), Cells(b + 32, 20)).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

The code can be executed, however, the output in the new sheet is empty. There will be 20 multiple empty blocks been copied into the new sheet. 
Send Help!!!

Comment: What do you  mean "20 multiple blocks"? And can you give the for-loop as well?

Comment: thanks for the help. However, it still copies blank blocks instead of the data that I wish to see.

Comment: Alas, you can't select numbers *and* copy/paste them. The only thing you can do is just selecting numbers and only if they are a result of formula (`F5 -> Special -> Formulas -> Numbers`).

Comment: @JosephYangShihao It would be great if you attach the example and your **For** loop as well so that we can identify what is the root cause and understand the big picture...:)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
b = 1 + 35 * a    

Range(Cells(42, 1), Cells(86, 20)).Copy 'consider using sheet reference here, like below :)
Sheets("output").Range(Cells(b, 1), Cells(b + 44, 20)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False
```

First, I took care of ranges, so their dimensions match.

Secondly, it is highly recommended **not to use** `Select` and `Selection`. Use references instead as I did. It also increases readability of a code.